# Swift UITableViewController didSelectRow first called when second cell selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So here's my strange problem.
I have a small app which uses storyboard.
I have 1 `UITabBarController` which has 2 tabs:
- 1 `UITableViewController`(subclassed)
- 1 `UIViewController`(just has a UILabel and does nothing till now)

The UITableViewController is subclassed and i provided:
- `numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int`
- `tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int`
- `tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`
- `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

The tableview has 2 sections (7 and 1 row).
The rows in section 1 are custom cells and should do nothing when selected.
The row in section 2 is a standard `UITableViewCell` and should start a download.
But When i selecting any cell `tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`isn't even called, only after selecting another cell(not the same again), the didSelect will be called with the first cell i selected.
Another example; (x,x) is representing the selected indexPath
(1,0), does nothing -> (0,6), (1,0) is selected -> (0,2), (0,6) is selected -> (1,0), (0,2) is selected

Additions:
- The highlighting is working as it should. Just the call of `tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` isn't.
- `tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath?` is called appropriate.

Solution:
Was a little typo in the delegate method. I implemented `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. 
You should use this method :

```
tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

Comment: holy crap, thank you. these typos

Answer (score 1):

Please check your delegate method, it should be;

```
tableView(tableView: UITableView, selectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

Comment: there is no selectRowAtIndexPath method in the UITableViewDelegate protocol. willSelectRow exists and is called appropriate, just the didSelect isn't called, from the other anwser i might know what you meant

Comment: Sorry, it's didSelect. See the answer below for exact syntax. You can check the delegate definition.